# Limit probability for a ball in box problem

Tags: probability

Let n balls are randomly placed in 2n cells. Let X denote the no. Of balls occupying the 1st cell . Find lim n tends to infinity P(X=5) ??

As far as I got into my thoughts is:
If X=5 then rest balls =n-5, rest cells=2n-1
n-5 balls placed in 2n-1 cells in 2n-1Cn-5 ways.

I m not sure if these hav anything to do with the question. Is this a WLLN?

Comment: What the hell is a WLLN?

Comment: Do you mean $\lim n\to \infty$?

Comment: @Randall weak law of large numbers

Comment: Ah, thank you.  My ignorance.

Comment: Oh yeah it was a typo!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of this as the number of successes in $n$ independent attempts, each with probability $\frac{1}{2n}.$ The probability of five successes is given exactly by $${n\choose 5}\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^5\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{n-5}.$$

Alternatively to directly taking the limit of this expression, you should recognize this as the Poisson limit of the binomial (where there are many attempts at low probability). The "success rate" is $1/2,$ so we want the probability that $X=5$ when $X$ is a Poisson with mean $1/2.$ This is $$e^{-1/2} \frac{(1/2)^5}{5!}.$$